# Convert Excel VBA to VB.Net with Selection.ListObject.QueryTable Intact

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I need to access the `Selection.ListObject.QueryTable` object in order to preserve the column width.

The code is as follows:

```
Range("B9").Select()
With Selection.ListObject.QueryTable
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = False
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
End With
```

What is the VB.Net version of this Excel-generated VBA code?

Comment: You should mark Phillip's answer as correct.

Answer (score 5):

What about something like this?

```
Dim excelApp AS Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
excelApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=_file)

With excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(0).Cells(9, 2).QueryTable
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = 1
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = False
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
End With
```

where `_file` is the name of your Excel file.